# gdb: malloc(): memory corruption (fast):

Tags: gdb

When executing gdb> core-file , gdb gives the following errors and then crashes creating a core file:

```
Reading symbols from ./libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0...
*** glibc detected *** gdb: malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000000ec04a0 ***
```

I haven't found any reference to gdb crashing with this error. Has anyone run into this? If so what can be done about it.

The version of GDB is: GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (6.8.50.20090302-1.5.18)

Thanks

Comment: Compile with `-g`. Does it say anything about some line number ? Care to show some minimal compilable code exhibiting the problem ?

Comment: I am not compiling the code myself - just trying to get a stack trace to submit for analysis. Just to clarify, this error occurs when running gdb to analyze a core, not when the app itself is running.

Comment: Try invoking gdb with program and core file name as arguments, i.e. 'gdb prog-file core-file'

Comment: Invoking from the command line gives the same error (different memory location), then during memory map, gdb cores

Comment: It turns out the malloc error was due to the order of paths in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. tcmalloc was in the var ahead of the O/S memory manager. Changing the order eliminated this error.

Now I have a different error, but that's a subject for another post.

Answer (score 0):

> what can be done about it

Any crash in GDB itself *is* a bug.

However, nobody would care about this bug, unless it can be reproduced with *current* GDB (yours is 5 years old).

So, [download](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/) current release of GDB (7.5.1 currently), and build it.

If it works, use it to debug your problem.

If it doesn't work, file a bug in GDB [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb).

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error as a result of calling

```
ptr = (ptr_t*)malloc(sizeof(ptr_t));
```

in your program, it may be due a missing stdlib.h header.